# How do I combine rowwise values of 2D Numpy array into one single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a 2D numpy array as shown below

```
[['me' 'you']
 ['her' 'him']]
```

I want to get a numpy array like this

```
['meyou'
'herhim']
```

which should be a 1D numpy array

How do I do it in the most efficient way in terms of speed?

Comment: How ever you do it, it's a python string operation. Even with np.char.  So there's no superfast array approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simply "add" the two columns using NumPy's string manipulation:

```
 np.char.add(x[:,0], x[:,1])
```

Or more generally, for any number of columns, here is a simple solution (if the number of columns is large, this is not efficient):

```
from functools import reduce # not needed in Python 2
reduce(np.char.add, x.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, whereby you join all the values within the same sublist together:

```
["".join(i) for i in x]

['meyou', 'herhim']
```

Comment: Even if you take into account casting this back into a numpy array it's faster than using `numpy` methods